# Recursively walk directories with a callback function

Tags: recursion, callback, julia, file-system

This code works, but I want to refine it:

```
# =======================
# Dir Walk
#
# This will recursively walk a directory
# ========================

function dirwalk(path::AbstractString, fn::Function)
  content = readdir(path)
  for c in content
    p = joinpath(path, c)
    if isdir(p)
      dirwalk(p, fn)
    elseif isfile(p)
      fn(p)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use a docstring instead of a comment:

```
"""Recursively walk a directory."""
function [ . . . ]
```

Using a docstring allows Julia's built-in help features to work with your function.

Next, I would recommend putting the function argument *first*:

```
function dirwalk(fn::Function, path::AbstractString)
```

Why? This allows `dirwalk` to be used with Julia's `do` block syntax:

```
dirwalk("path/to/file") do p
    # do stuff with p, the path
end
```

which is often nicer than using anonymous function syntax.

Now for the function itself, you don't need a temporary variable to store `content`. This:

```
for c in readdir(path)
```

is shorter and reads just as well. Inside the loop, things generally look fine (except the order of `dirwalk` could be reversed). Note that your implementation ignores symlinks, which are neither directories nor regular files.

As for style, the Julia style guide recommends 4-space indenting. Some projects use 2-space indenting, however, and that is a personal decision.

Finally, you might be interested in the `walkdir` function.